# python regex: replacing string in a pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

First-time post, please be patient.

I'm having some trouble matching strings and then replacing them. Here is what my Series looks like:

```
                          place_of_death
1                           Baghdad 
2                            Kirkuk
3                            Tallil
4                             Babil
5                            Kirkuk
6                          Baghdad 
...                         ...
26      Baghdad (southeastern part)
```

I have a lot of entries like #26 with extraneous information. All I'm trying to do is trim off the end part of the string just to have the "Baghdad" part in the Series. Here is what I've tried, which doesn't throw an error but also doesn't do what I'm hoping to do:

```
df['place_of_death'].replace(to_replace= 'r(^Baghdad+)', value='Baghdad',regex=True)
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm not very familiar with regex so I'm hoping to learn more.

Comment: Is that extra info only with string `Baghdad` ?

Comment: Are all the place names nominally single word length? For instance could you do `df['place_of_death'] = df['place_of_death'].str.split().str[0]`?

Comment: No, there is extra information for multiple cities. And no, the place names are not of single word length. Sorry for not being so specific.

Comment: You might be able to remove everything between parenthesis.

Comment: For the erroneous entries is the pattern always with a space and braces? So would `df['place_of_death'] = df['place_of_death'].str.split(' ('
).str[0]` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `(extra info)` appearing at the end of each string using following regex.

**Regex:** `\(.*?\)$` replace with `empty string -> ""`

**Explanation:**

- `\(.*?\)$` looks for string enclosed in parenthesis at the **end** of each string.

**Flag to use:**

- `g` for global search.
- `m` for multi-line search.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU2vP9/1)**

Comment: @red_eggs: Am glad it did.